# Bootstrap NavTab from Database

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I have the following table:

```
---------------------------
oName          Dept
---------------------------
Roo           IT
Max           MKT
Tom           MKT
```

Then I have the following script on my controller:

```
ViewBag.GetoName = (from a in _db.TbEmp
     where a.Dept == "MKT"
     select new {
          a.oName
     }
).ToList();
```

I want to load the list above into a navTab on my View. How can I do that? So the navTab bootstrap would be:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#max">Max</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tom">Tom</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="max">
    <p>Content1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tom">
    <p>Content2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `oName` to be nav_link name,and `Dept` to be Content.Here is a demo:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @{ var count = 0;}
    @foreach (var sample in ViewBag.GetoName)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#@sample.oName">@sample.oName</a>
            </li>
        }
        else { 
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#@sample.oName">@sample.oName</a>
            </li>
        }
        count++;
    }
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    @{ var count1 = 0;}
    @foreach (var sample in ViewBag.GetoName)
    {

        if (count1 == 0)
        {
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="@sample.oName">
                <p>@sample.Dept</p>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="@sample.oName">
                <p>@sample.Dept</p>
            </div>
        }
        count1++;
    }
</div>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This is great and works. Thank you so much. I have a question, how can I make 'Active` for the first-tab?

Comment: Hello,I have updated my answer to make `Active` for the first-tab.